# Android TCP Server limitation

Tags: java, android, tcp

I need to maintain TCP Server in my Android app.

- In my application I had connected 12 clients.
- All clients are in active.
- After some period of time, one or more clients are getting
  connection time out.

**I need to know, how many clients can be connect with my TCP server without connection time out.**

Note: My server Device has a 2GB RAM.Other has 512 RAM, but all devices are android only. 
Is the number of clients is various depends upon the RAM Limit ?

- Wakelock is implemented for all the devices.
- All devices are fully charged.
- WIFI router is available within 6 feet distance, so there is no signal problem

Comment: You are *assuming,* and *without proof,* that it has something to do with the number of clients. It doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you are trying to say. But this is my situation, in the above case, I had faced the connection timeout at client side. With the help of timeout exception log, i come to know about the issue. So only I had raised my doubt in Stackoverflow. Do you have any ideas help me for this case. @EJP

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the disconnect is happening because the device is going into a low power state, disabling or sleeping the network interface.  Of course, this assumes that your network link is stable (you are not roaming via Wifi or mobile network.)  If you need to keep all clients connected and prevent sleep, you'll need to take and hold a wakelock to prevent sleep.  It is a tradeoff you need to decide upon, though.  As long as you are holding the wakelock, the system will not enter low power state(s) and you will consume more battery.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Wakelock is implemented for all the clients and All the devices are running with full battery charge. All devices are connected into wifi, distance between all devices and wifi router is just 6 feets only. In this case, one of the device is getting disconnected. So only I had posted this question